# angularJS call php method POST 405 not allowed

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to save data in database, Im using angular and I used a file php to access to database, the problem is : POST http://127.0.0.1:9090/insert_indispo.php 405 (Method Not Allowed).. please how to resolve this problem !......

here my function post:

```js
function ValideConge(id,debut,fin) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
 
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: window.location.href + 'insert_indispo.php',
                data: {id,debut,fin},
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).then(function (success){
                deferred.resolve("ok!");
                console.log("ok c!");
            },function (error){
                deferred.resolve(false);
                console.log("ok n!");
            });
            return deferred.promise;
 
        }
```

here my file php :

```js
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
 
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $id = $request->id;
    $debut = $request->debut;
    $fin = $request->fin;
 
 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "plann";
 
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO indisp (id_form,date_debut,date_fin)
VALUES ( $id, $debut , $fin)";
 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "ajouté avec succé !";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is your server based on?

Comment: Bonus : Your SQL request is sensitive at SQL injection.

Comment: I'm working under 127.1.1.0/9090      , but I changed the url to http://localhost it work but with this error :   Error: INSERT INTO indisp (id_formateur,date_debut,date_fin) VALUES ( 0, 2017-04-05 , 2017-04-07)
Incorrect date value: '2008' for column 'date_debut' at row 1

Comment: Could you please answer my question? What is your server based on Apache, IIS, NGINX? 405 is depending on your server configuration not on the your codes.

Comment: please how to find the server ? I found this in header response (chrome) Server:Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25